# ClassCastException when reading excel file with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an Excel (.xlsx) file using POI, but for some strange reason it keeps coming up with the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.**impl.ThemeDocumentImpl** cannot be cast to org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.**ThemeDocument**

I am using the following POI 3.7 libraries (the system doesn't allow us to update)

- poi-3.7-20101029.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-20101029.jar

The code is as follows.

```
/**
 * @param fileName
 * @param outputName
 */
override function parseAndConverToCSVFile(fileName : String, outputName : String) {
  var lineCount = 0
  var file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName))
  var wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file)
  var sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0)
  var row : XSSFRow

  ...
}
```

The exception is thrown when a new workbook is created, with the following message.

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.impl.ThemeDocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:59)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:277)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:186)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:189)
        at full.path.package.name.CappingDataImportUtility.parseAndConverToCSVFile(CappingDataImportUtility.gs:57)`

What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure there  is not additional a `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` in class path. But if it is it needs fit to the `apache poi` version used. For version `3.7`  October 2010 it needs to be ``ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar`.

Comment: @AxelRichter There is an ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar. I have tried removing it, but the problem persists.

Comment: Why are you using a version of Apache POI that is nearly 9 years old? What happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr That is how I found the system, with the old libs. When I replace it with the latest libs then things break all over the place. As much as I want to, I can't just go around changing what is there without red tape change request corporate BS. Also, the test effort would be substantial and I won't be able to get away with it under the radar.

Comment: Point your management at [the list of CVEs in Apache POI fixed in newer versions](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html), then get a plan approved to upgrade to a new version with no known security issues? :)